# Scala: using JNI native methods in traits

Tags: scala, java-native-interface, traits

I have a class successfully using a number of JNI methods. However I want to change it to a trait and I can't get the right function signatures for the C++ file. The Scalac compiler produces a class file for the trait with the same name as the class. When I run javah on this class file it gives me the same c function signatures as with the class But those signatures give me:

Method xOpen in class pXClient/XCClass has illegal modifiers: 0x501

The original class offers methods for the xlib library, but I want to have alternatives for Opengl on top of Xlib and opengl on top of xcb as well as just xcb. Later combinations could be for Wayland or Opengl on a Windows client. So the methods need to be broken up into traits that can be mixed in.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways of handling this:

1) You use standard OOP composition:

```
trait MyIntefaceIWantToExpose{
  def foo(bar: Baz)
}

class MyRealized extends MyJniClass with MyInterfaceIWantToExpose

class SomeOtherClass(stuff: MyInterfaceIWantToExpose){
  def something(bar: Baz){
    stuff foo bar
  }
}
```

Wherein you may need to pass along an actual implementation for your "MyRealized" which delegates function calls to the JNI class.

```
class MyJni{
  def add(x: Int):Int = { /* native code */ }
}

trait MyInterface{
  def thing(x: Int): Int
}

class MyRealized extends MyJni with MyInterface{
  def thing(x: Int) = add(x)
}
```

2) A trait can extend a class, make it abstract with no constructors:

```
trait MyExtention extends MyJniClass{
  def whole(lotta: Love): Yay
}
```

Do note that this is equivalent to the following (more or less):

```
trait MyExtention{
  self: MyJniClass =>
}
```

which is a self type or a constraint that says the class you're working with must extend the class "MyJniClass."

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I want to be able to mixin the jni methods with other classes.

Comment: You're going to have to either use composition or would with a delegate. I'll update.